# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x)/(x^2+1)$ using complex analysis.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

Using **only** complex analysis.

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx = (\frac{1}{2})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

Consider a contour $C$ with a **upper-axis** semi-circle $B$ and the axis running from $-R \to R$

We will compute:

$$\oint_{C} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2 + 1} dz$$

First:

$$z^2 + 1 = 0 \implies Z \in \{-i, i\}$$

Only, $z = i$ is in the semi circle region.

$$\text{Res}_{z=i} = \lim_{z \to i} (z-i)(f(i)) = \lim_{z \to i} \frac{\cos(z)}{z + i} = \frac{\cosh(1)}{2i}$$

Applying the residue theorem:

$$\oint_{C} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2 + 1} dz = (2\pi i)\cdot \frac{\cosh(1)}{2i} = \pi\cdot\cosh(1)$$

$$\oint_{C} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2 + 1} dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

But that is wrong, the answer for the full improper is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx = \frac{\pi}{e}$$

What am I doing **wrong?**

Comment: You seem to be confused about the use of $e^{iz}$ in the given answers. Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: I am aware of eulers formula. But it states: $e^{iz} = \cos(z) + i\sin(z)$ it includes $\sin(z)$ as well. Which is why you cant just substitute $e^{iz} = \cos(z)$ which is wrong. It is true that Re[$e^{iz}$] = $\cos(z)$ but how can we implement that looking at the contour top half of plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cosine function does not vanish on the semicircle as $R \to \infty$; in fact, it does the opposite.  You need to either 1) take the real part of $e^{i x}$ in the upper half plane, or 2) use $\cos{x} = (e^{i x}+e^{-i x})/2$ and use both the upper and lower half planes, respectively.

Comment: so I chose the wrong contour? Can you please address how to choose a contour here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077554/choosing-a-contour-to-integrate-over?

It could help very much.

Comment: @Amad27: you didn't choose the wrong contour necessarily.  You chose the wrong function to integrate over that contour.  It seems to me, looking at your work, that you have omitted working out the piece that involves the integral over the semicircle.  You really need to work it out to see what's going on.

Comment: But if we look at the function respectively. Should I have chosen a different contour?

Comment: @Amad27: please read my answer.  If you choose option 1), then no, you don't have to.

Comment: What is the real "part" of $e^{ix}$? $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ so, its still $\cos(x)$

Comment: @Amad27: you write the cosine as the real part of the exp.  The integral you seek is then the real part of the integral of exp divided by $1+x^2$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the "real part," terminology. What does that mean? What is the real part of $e^{ix}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19669/discussion-between-amad27-and-ron-gordon).

Comment: @Amad27: actually, I'll pass.  I'm a bit busy.  If you're taking complex analysis and don't know what I am talking about, then you have some reading to do.

Comment: if you are free now, and have a minute, will you be able to guide me with one more question? $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ if we use this as cosine, in our problem, it comes out incorrect? Because it also involves the sine into it.

Answer (score 5):

we use  $$f\left( z \right) = \frac{{e^{iz} }}{{1 + z^2 }}$$

Comment: Why $e^{iz}$ instead of $\cos(z)$??

Comment: The integral on the semicircle of $e^{iz}$ goes to zero.  The integral on the semicircle of $\cos z$ does not.

Comment: But the problem statement says cosine ???

Comment: $\cos (z)$ is the real part of $e^{iz}$

Answer (score 1):

we use  $$f\left( z \right) = \frac{{e^{iz} }}{{1 + z^2 }}$$
then take real parts of the resulting integral .using the same contour $C$

### [image]

\begin{array}{l}
 i \in C; - i \notin C \\ 
 {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} s\left( {f;i} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to i} \left\{ {\left( {z - i} \right)\frac{{e^{iz} }}{{1 + z^2 }}} \right\} = \frac{{e^{ - 1} }}{{2i}} \\ 
 \end{array}
\begin{array}{l}
 \oint\limits_C {\frac{{e^{iz} }}{{1 + z^2 }}dz}  = \int\limits_{ - R}^{ + R} {\frac{{e^{ix} dx}}{{1 + x^2 }}}  + \int\limits_{S_R}  {\frac{{e^{iz} dz}}{{1 + z^2 }}}  = 
2\pi i\frac{{e^{ - 1} }}{{2i}} = \frac{\pi }{e} \\ 
  \Rightarrow \int\limits_{ - R}^{ + R} {\frac{{\cos \left( x \right)dx}}{{1 + x^2 }}}  + i\int\limits_{ - R}^{ + R} {\frac{{\sin \left( x \right)dx}}{{1 + x^2 }} + } \int\limits_{S_R}  {\frac{{e^{iz} dz}}{{1 + z^2 }}}  = \pi e^{ - 1}  \\ 
 2\int\limits_0^{ + R} {\frac{{\cos \left( x \right)dx}}{{1 + x^2 }}}  = \pi e^{ - 1} ;\quad \left( {\int\limits_{S_R}  {\frac{{e^{ix} dx}}{{1 + x^2 }} = 0} ;R \to  + \infty \int\limits_{ - R}^{ + R} {\frac{{\sin \left( x \right)dx}}{{1 + x^2 }} = 0} } \right) \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to  + \infty } \int\limits_0^{ + R} {\frac{{\cos \left( x \right)dx}}{{1 + x^2 }}}  = \frac{\pi }{2}e^{ - 1}  \\ 
 \end{array}

note:
but if $y = {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \left( z \right)$ then $\cos \left( z \right) \approx \frac{{e^{\left| y \right|} }}{{\left| z \right|^2 }}$ for large $\left| z \right|$

we have the estimate 
$
\left| {\int\limits_{C_R } {\frac{{e^{iz} }}{{z^2  + 1}}dz} } \right| \le \int\limits_{C_R } {\frac{{e^{ - y} }}{{R^2  - 1}}\left| {dz} \right|}  \le \frac{{\pi R}}{{R^2  - 1}} \to 0
$ as  $R \to \infty $ 
where $
y = {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \left( z \right) > 0
$by the residue theorem
$
\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ix} }}{{x^2  + 1}}dx = } 2\pi i\sum\limits_{{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} a > 0} {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} s_a } \frac{{e^{iz} }}{{z^2  + 1}} = \frac{\pi }{e}
$

Comment: how come you aren't using $\cos(z)$ ??

Comment: @Amad27 $\cos(x)$ is the real part of $\exp(ix)$. So one should instead evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(ix)}{x^2+1}dx$, and take the real part of this integral, in order to find the integral you want.